# How to include group by in view tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following script.

```
drop view proba;
create view proba as
select distinct oper as p_name
, sum(duration) as out_duration 
from TA_OUT 
where oper in ('CZE','FRA')
and timestamp like '201306%' 
group by oper;

drop view proba1;
create view proba1 as
select distinct oper as p_name
,sum(duration) as in_duration 
from TA_IN 
where oper in ('CZE','FRA')
and timestamp like '201306%'
group by oper;

drop view proba3; 
create view proba3 as
select distinct oper as p_name
,sum(duration) as out_duration 
from TA_OUT
where oper in ('CZE','FRA')
and timestamp like '201305%' 
group by oper;

drop view proba4;
create view proba4 as
select distinct oper as p_name
,sum(duration) as in_duration 
from TA_IN 
where oper in ('CZE','FRA')
and timestamp like '201305%'
group by oper;

drop view proba2;
create view proba2 as
select distinct oper as p_name 
from OPER_DESCRIPTION;
```

The idea of this code is to receive duration for different months and after that in the next code to compare this duration. This is the next code.

```
drop view proba5;

CREATE VIEW proba5 AS
SELECT (BAL1 + BAL2) AS BAL
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE

            WHEN proba.out_duration <= proba1.in_duration
             AND proba.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
             AND proba1.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
            THEN (proba.out_duration / 60) * 0.14

            WHEN proba.out_duration > proba1.in_duration
             AND proba.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
             AND proba1.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
            THEN
                (proba1.in_duration / 60) * 0.14
                +
                ((proba.out_duration - proba1.in_duration) / 60) * 0.09

            ELSE 0

        END AS BAL1

        , CASE

            WHEN proba3.out_duration <= proba4.in_duration
             AND proba3.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
             AND proba4.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
            THEN (proba3.out_duration / 60) * 0.14

            WHEN proba3.out_duration > proba4.in_duration
             AND proba3.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
             AND proba4.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
            THEN
                (proba4.in_duration / 60) * 0.14
                + ((proba3.out_duration - proba4.in_duration) / 60) * 0.09

            ELSE 0

        END AS BAL2

    FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    proba2
                    LEFT JOIN proba
                        ON proba2.p_name = proba.p_name
                )
                LEFT JOIN proba1
                    ON proba1.p_name = proba1.p_name
                LEFT JOIN proba3
                    ON proba3.p_name = proba3.p_name
            )
            LEFT JOIN proba4
                ON proba4.p_name = proba4.p_name
        )
        WHERE proba.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
        AND proba1.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
        AND proba3.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
        AND proba4.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
    )
);
```

When I use one p_name, for instance "CZE" I receive the correct total duration. I want to receive distinct duration for every P_name. For example:

```
CZE 500
FRA 1300
```

However, the problem is that I am not able to group by p_name only, because I should include group by duration too.

Could you please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: "However, the problem is that I am not able to group by p_name only, because I should include group by duration too." - Why?

Comment: Looking at your initial view, you've got `distinct` and `group by` on the same field - FYI: when using `group by` that value's distinct by definition.  e.g. if you had a bunch of black and white balls and you grouped them into bags, you'd have two distinct bags - one containing white balls and one black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code below should do what all those views combined are attempting / hopefully it's also easier to see what's going on:

```
create view probAll as
select coalesce(tin.oper,tout.oper) as p_name
, sum
    (
        0.14 * tout.duration / 60 
        + case 
            when tout.duration > tin.duration
            then 0.09 * (tout.duration - tin.duration) / 60
            else 0
        end
    )
from 

(
    select oper
    , EXTRACT(Year FROM DATE timestamp) as tYear
    , EXTRACT(Month FROM DATE timestamp) as tMonth
    , sum(duration) as Balance
    from TA_OUT
    group by oper
    , EXTRACT(Year FROM DATE timestamp)
    , EXTRACT(Month FROM DATE timestamp) 
) as tout

full outer join

(    
    select oper
    , EXTRACT(Year FROM DATE timestamp) as tYear
    , EXTRACT(Month FROM DATE timestamp) as tMonth
    , sum(duration) as Balance
    from TA_IN
    group by oper
    , EXTRACT(Year FROM DATE timestamp)
    , EXTRACT(Month FROM DATE timestamp) 
) as tin

on tin.oper = tout.oper
and tin.tyear = tout.tyear
and tin.tmonth = tout.tmonth

where coalesce(tin.oper,tout.oper) in ('CZE','FRA')
and coalesce(tin.tyear,tout.tyear) = 2013
and coalesce(tin.tmonth,tout.tmonth) in (5, 6)

group by coalesce(tin.oper,tout.oper)
```

(untested)

Comment: Thanks for helping me and for explanation about "group by" and "distinct" it was really useful. The script above gives me the error: "ORA-00936:missing expression", i think that it is because the field timestamp it is Varchar2 (not date).

Comment: Ah ok - makes sense.  You can either cast it from string to date,  substring the field for the first 6 chars (yyyymm) or use like statements as per your original.  Personally I'd recommend converting the type of that column to a date if you're able though - assuming it will always contain dates; it'll pay off in functionality and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one out:

```
CREATE VIEW proba5
AS
SELECT p_name, SUM(BAL1 + BAL2) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        proba.p_name, 
        CASE
            WHEN     proba.out_duration <= proba1.in_duration
                THEN     proba.out_duration / 60) * 0.14
            WHEN     proba.out_duration > proba1.in_duration
                THEN     (proba1.in_duration / 60) * 0.14
                       + ((proba.out_duration - proba1.in_duration)/60) * 0.09
            ELSE 0
        END AS BAL1,
        CASE
            WHEN     proba3.out_duration <= proba4.in_duration
                THEN  (proba3.out_duration / 60) * 0.14
            WHEN     proba3.out_duration > proba4.in_duration
                THEN    (proba4.in_duration / 60) * 0.14
                       + ((proba3.out_duration - proba4.in_duration)/60) * 0.09
            ELSE 0
        END AS BAL2
    FROM proba2
        LEFT JOIN proba  ON proba2.p_name = proba.p_name
        LEFT JOIN proba1 ON proba1.p_name = proba1.p_name
        LEFT JOIN proba3 ON proba3.p_name = proba3.p_name
        LEFT JOIN proba4 ON proba4.p_name = proba4.p_name
    WHERE     
        proba.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
    AND proba1.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
    AND proba3.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
    AND proba4.p_name IN ('CZE', 'FRA')
)
    GROUP BY proba.p_name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The script is working, I just put after "SELECT proba.p_name as p_name" because without this alias it gave me the error "ORA: Invalid indentifire"

Comment: @DejanIvanov Hi! I'm sorting out my last answers. I see this one has not gotten accepted. Did you have any further problem? If it solved your problem, don't forget that upvote + accept is the best reward ;) Thanks and have a great day.